# f:ajax not working on tomcat7/eclipse

Tags: ajax, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, mojarra

I have this very simple code which works fine until I add a `f:ajax` tag.

Code that works:

```
<h:commandButton disabled="#{!feature.available}" class="featureButton"
        value="#{feature.selected ? 'selected': feature.available? 'available':'unavailable'} "
        style="vertical-align: top;" action="#{Bean.toggleFeature(feature)}">
    </h:commandButton>
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
<h:commandButton disabled="#{!feature.available}" class="featureButton"
        value="#{feature.selected ? 'selected': feature.available? 'available':'unavailable'} "
        style="vertical-align: top;" action="#{Bean.toggleFeature(feature)}">
        <f:ajax event="click"  />
</h:commandButton>
```

As far as I can tell the jsf.js file is loaded fine, this is automatically added by the facelet servlet to the head of my rendered document
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/www/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces"></script>` and I was even able to do a `jsf.ajax.request` directly from javascript and got the page to rerender something.

I am using mojarra 2.1.13, tomcat 7, eclipse juno, java 7.

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong or how I might be able to troubleshoot this issue? debugging it in javascript didn't help at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to mention above that I had nested ui:repeats and it turns out there is a bug with mojarra regarding that. As far as I can tell the fix has just been committed but it isn't out as a jar yet however I tried myfaces and it worked fine, so I'll do that for now. Here are the bug details:

http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1817

Comment: Just tested it on mojarra 2.1.16 and it is fixed.